# How to scale image as center crop and apply width of wrap content on it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I believe that there are many Android developers which have been looking for replacements for match_parent and wrap_content properties in Flutter development. I have a situation in which I have to place an image that should have a height of 210.0 and take the width of the parent. Due to the real image has sizes that are much bigger, I am facing the problem that it is displayed cropped and some parts of an image are missed.

Has anyone idea how I can gain that the image uses the width of the parent and fits in the defined height of 210.0 but still be shown in its full capacity? In Android XML, I would solve it by setting the width to wrap content and scale the image with centerCrop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official documentation, I believe [BoxFit enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) covers what you need.

If I understood your question correctly, `BoxFit.fitHeight` will do the job:

```
SizedBox(
      height: 210,
      child: Image.network(
        'https://picsum.photos/2560/1440?image=29',
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      )
  )
```

If you want to fiddle around with it (like try other BoxFits, change device width on the fly...) I've made this DartPad for you:
https://dartpad.dev/fca40b807b3698067e9a923474cb0394

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain with a bit more clarity what you are trying to achieve. By that I mean:

1. Refrain from comparing your approach in other frameworks as the main way of explaining what you want. SO users browsing fluter and dart might or might not be familiar with android xml layouts.
2. A couple of simple sketches are good for getting the point across when working on UI.
3. You didn't say if you want to maintain aspect ratio or not. I'm guessing you do want to maintain aspect ratio but in that case the image will either have to be shrunk down(not "*in its full capacity*") or cropped ("*parts of an image are missed*."), you can't have it both without distorting aspect ratio.